# Alarm Clock streaming internet radio

Tags: wifi, audio, music, alarm-clock

I live in a region where I don't have the luxury to have my radio channels of choice on the FM band, but I am addicted to waking up with the chatter of the radio.

Do you know of any well-designed alarm clock that treats internet radio streams the same way the other alarm clocks treat FM radio? Namely, being able to use internet radio presets as the morning alarm.

Note: I don't want a bedside computer, but rather a simple product like [Wakey](https://www.soundcore.com/products/variant/wakey/A3300121) minus FM plus internet radio.

Comment: What counts as a "bedside computer"? Would an Alexa/Google Home/HomeKit enabled device be acceptable?

Comment: Definitely, is it is simple and looks like a clock with dimmable light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the product you linked and your aversion to "bedside computers", I selected alarms with a similar rear-projection type display.

## Echo Dot (3rd gen) with clock - $45

[image]

Luckily for you, Amazon has an upcoming version of the Alexa-equipped Echo Dot that meets all the requirements. It's got a dimmable display, all the normal Alexa bells and whistles (including Bluetooth and Hue integration), and supports musical alarms with TuneIn, SiriusXM, and iHeartRadio (and if you have a change of heart and and decide to switch to to a streaming service, Amazon Music, Spotify, and Pandora.) Best of all, like all rest of the Echo line, it's quite cheap (as the hardware costs are subsidized by Amazon.) Unfortunately, they won't be back in stock until March 1st, 2020, but as long as you're willing to wait, it's a pretty solid box.

## Sony S50G - $200

[image]

If you want better sound quality, prefer Google Assistant to Alexa, or just don't want to be quite so basic, Sony sells the SG50. Just like the Echo Dot, it's got Bluetooth, a dimmable display, and all the fancy bells and whistles that come with Google Assistant, including support for TuneIn, SiriusXM, and iHeartRadio (and again, Google Play Music, YouTube Music, Spotify, and Pandora.) Do note that there have been some (not super widespread?) [reports of issues](https://piunikaweb.com/2019/06/07/google-home-radio-alarms-not-working-for-many-company-aware/) with internet radio on Google Assistant though.

Answer (score 0):

The company **Ocean Digital** seems to have several devices like this.

For example:

- [**Ocean Digital Wi-Fi Internet Radios WR828F FM Receiver with Airmusic Control APP & Sleep Radio- for Sleeping & Relaxation Alarm Clock Stereo Dual Speaker with USB Port**](https://amzn.to/35QQNzZ)
- [**Ocean Digital WiFi/FM Internet Radio WR230S Alarm Clock Radio with Bluetooth Receiver & Ethernet Port, Stereo Speakers, Line Out, Aux in, 20,000+ Stations, 2.4" Color Display- Black in Wooden Case**](https://amzn.to/2soAYmx)